# Can't view SSRS report manager and report generation failed

Tags: reporting-services

in our production client environment ,the report manager show this message when we try to access to the site :
An error occurred within the report server database. This may be due to a connection failure, timeout or low disk condition within the database. (rsReportServerDatabaseError)"

the database storage is enough and i can connect to the instance

ReportServer Log Trace:

```
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!1b18!10/31/2019-22:18:10:: i INFO: Appdomain:3 ReportManager_IFCLPROD_0-1-132170302898216319 started.
appdomainmanager!ReportManager_0-1!1b18!10/31/2019-22:18:12:: i INFO: RS authentication mode is 4; effective ASP.NET authentication mode is Windows. vdir=/Reports_IFCLPROD.
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!1b18!10/31/2019-22:18:12:: i INFO: Appdomain:3 ReportManager_IFCLPROD_0-1-132170302898216319 initialized (#1).
library!ReportManager_0-1!1b18!10/31/2019-22:18:13:: i INFO: SQLDump flags: ReferencedMemory, AllThreads, SendToWatson
library!ReportManager_0-1!1b18!10/31/2019-22:18:13:: i INFO: MiniDump flags: DataSegs, UnloadedModules, ProcessThreadData
library!ReportManager_0-1!1b18!10/31/2019-22:18:13:: i INFO: Dump on: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException,Microsoft.ReportingServices.Modeling.InternalModelingException,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException
library!ReportManager_0-1!1b18!10/31/2019-22:18:13:: i INFO: Do not dump on: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException,System.Web.UI.ViewStateException,System.OutOfMemoryException,System.Web.HttpException,System.IO.IOException,System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WMIProviderException
library!ReportManager_0-1!1b18!10/31/2019-22:18:13:: i INFO: Minidump location: E:\BD_SqlServer\Prod\MSRS11.IFCLPROD\Reporting Services\Logfiles
ui!ReportManager_0-1!1b18!10/31/2019-22:18:13:: i INFO: Registering with Software Usage Metrics Product:SQL Server 2012, Role:Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services, RoleGuid:8cc0ac85-40f7-4886-9dab-021519800418
ui!ReportManager_0-1!1b18!10/31/2019-22:18:13:: e ERROR: Software Usage Metrics initialize failed
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!18d4!10/31/2019-22:18:17:: i INFO: Appdomain:4 ReportServer_IFCLPROD_0-2-132170302970483545 started.
appdomainmanager!ReportServer_0-2!18d4!10/31/2019-22:18:19:: i INFO: RS authentication mode is 4; effective ASP.NET authentication mode is Windows. vdir=/ReportServer_IFCLPROD.
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!18d4!10/31/2019-22:18:19:: i INFO: Appdomain:4 ReportServer_IFCLPROD_0-2-132170302970483545 initialized (#1).
webserver!ReportServer_0-2!18d4!10/31/2019-22:18:25:: i INFO: Reporting Web Server started
library!ReportServer_0-2!18d4!10/31/2019-22:18:25:: i INFO: SQLDump flags: ReferencedMemory, AllThreads, SendToWatson
library!ReportServer_0-2!18d4!10/31/2019-22:18:25:: i INFO: MiniDump flags: DataSegs, UnloadedModules, ProcessThreadData
library!ReportServer_0-2!18d4!10/31/2019-22:18:25:: i INFO: Dump on: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.InternalCatalogException,Microsoft.ReportingServices.Modeling.InternalModelingException,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.UnhandledReportRenderingException
library!ReportServer_0-2!18d4!10/31/2019-22:18:25:: i INFO: Do not dump on: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException,System.Web.UI.ViewStateException,System.OutOfMemoryException,System.Web.HttpException,System.IO.IOException,System.IO.FileLoadException,Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException,Microsoft.ReportingServices.WmiProvider.WMIProviderException
library!ReportServer_0-2!18d4!10/31/2019-22:18:25:: i INFO: Minidump location: E:\BD_SqlServer\Prod\MSRS11.IFCLPROD\Reporting Services\Logfiles
resourceutilities!ReportServer_0-2!18d4!10/31/2019-22:18:25:: i INFO: Reporting Services starting SKU: Enterprise
ui!ReportServer_0-2!18d4!10/31/2019-22:18:25:: i INFO: Software Usage Metrics not enabled for Enterprise edition
library!ReportServer_0-2!d64!10/31/2019-22:18:28:: i INFO: Call to GetPermissionsAction(/).
library!ReportServer_0-2!d64!10/31/2019-22:18:28:: i INFO: Catalog SQL Server Edition = Enterprise
crypto!ReportServer_0-2!d64!10/31/2019-22:18:29:: i INFO: Initializing crypto as user: Host\_sqladmin
crypto!ReportServer_0-2!d64!10/31/2019-22:18:29:: i INFO: Exporting public key
crypto!ReportServer_0-2!d64!10/31/2019-22:18:29:: i INFO: Performing sku validation
crypto!ReportServer_0-2!d64!10/31/2019-22:18:29:: i INFO: Importing existing encryption key
library!ReportServer_0-2!1d10!10/31/2019-22:18:29:: i INFO: Call to GetPropertiesAction(/, PathBased).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1804!10/31/2019-22:19:32:: i INFO: Call to GetPropertiesAction(/, PathBased).
library!ReportServer_0-2!123c!10/31/2019-22:20:36:: i INFO: Call to GetSystemPermissionsAction().
library!ReportServer_0-2!1804!10/31/2019-22:20:36:: i INFO: Call to ListChildrenAction(/, False).
library!ReportServer_0-2!1804!10/31/2019-22:23:11:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: , Une erreur s'est produite dans la base de données du serveur de rapports. Cela peut être dû à un échec de connexion, un délai d'attente ou une insuffisance de l'espace disque au sein de la base de données.;
library!ReportServer_0-2!1804!10/31/2019-22:23:11:: e ERROR: Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: Une erreur s'est produite dans la base de données du serveur de rapports. Cela peut être dû à un échec de connexion, un délai d'attente ou une insuffisance de l'espace disque au sein de la base de données. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Expiration du délai d'attente. Le délai d'attente s'est écoulé avant la fin de l'opération ou le serveur ne répond pas.
ui!ReportManager_0-1!18dc!10/31/2019-22:23:11:: e ERROR: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Une erreur s'est produite dans la base de données du serveur de rapports. Cela peut être dû à un échec de connexion, un délai d'attente ou une insuffisance de l'espace disque au sein de la base de données. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: Une erreur s'est produite dans la base de données du serveur de rapports. Cela peut être dû à un échec de connexion, un délai d'attente ou une insuffisance de l'espace disque au sein de la base de données. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Expiration du délai d'attente. Le délai d'attente s'est écoulé avant la fin de l'opération ou le serveur ne répond pas.
   à Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2005Impl.ListChildren(String Item, Boolean Recursive, CatalogItemList& CatalogItems)
   à Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.ListChildren(String ItemPath, Boolean Recursive, CatalogItem[]& CatalogItems)
   à Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.FolderItems.LoadItems()
   à Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.SortableItems.Control_Init(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   à System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)
   à Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.FolderContentsPageCtrl.Control_Init(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   à System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)
   à Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.SharedArea.Control_Init(Object sender, EventArgs args)
   à System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)
   à Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.FolderPage.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   à System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   à System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)
   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)
   à System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
ui!ReportManager_0-1!18dc!10/31/2019-22:23:11:: e ERROR: HTTP status code --> 200
-------Details--------
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Une erreur s'est produite dans la base de données du serveur de rapports. Cela peut être dû à un échec de connexion, un délai d'attente ou une insuffisance de l'espace disque au sein de la base de données. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportServerStorageException: Une erreur s'est produite dans la base de données du serveur de rapports. Cela peut être dû à un échec de connexion, un délai d'attente ou une insuffisance de l'espace disque au sein de la base de données. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Expiration du délai d'attente. Le délai d'attente s'est écoulé avant la fin de l'opération ou le serveur ne répond pas.
   à Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.ReportingService2005Impl.ListChildren(String Item, Boolean Recursive, CatalogItemList& CatalogItems)
   à Microsoft.ReportingServices.WebServer.ReportingService2010.ListChildren(String ItemPath, Boolean Recursive, CatalogItem[]& CatalogItems)

   à Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.FolderItems.LoadItems()

   à Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.SortableItems.Control_Init(Object sender, EventArgs args)

   à System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)

   à Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.FolderContentsPageCtrl.Control_Init(Object sender, EventArgs args)

   à System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)

   à Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.SharedArea.Control_Init(Object sender, EventArgs args)

   à System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.AddedControl(Control control, Int32 index)

   à Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.FolderPage.Page_Init(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   à System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   à System.Web.UI.Page.OnInit(EventArgs e)

   à System.Web.UI.Control.InitRecursive(Control namingContainer)

   à System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
library!ReportServer_0-2!123c!10/31/2019-22:23:11:: i INFO: Call to GetSystemPropertiesAction().
ui!ReportManager_0-1!18dc!10/31/2019-22:23:11:: e ERROR: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Le thread a été abandonné.
   à System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   à System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   à System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   à Microsoft.ReportingServices.UI.ReportingPage.ShowErrorPage(String errMsg)
webserver!ReportServer_0-2!11b0!10/31/2019-22:24:38:: i INFO: Reporting Web Server stopped
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!1288!10/31/2019-22:24:43:: i INFO: Appdomain:4 ReportServer_IFCLPROD_0-2-132170302970483545 unregistered.
rshost!rshost!1288!10/31/2019-22:24:43:: i INFO: Application domain type ReportServer statistics: created: 1, unloaded: 1, failed: 0, timed out: 0.
appdomainmanager!DefaultDomain!1288!10/31/2019-22:25:49:: i INFO: Appdomain:3 ReportManager_IFCLPROD_0-1-132170302898216319 unregistered.
rshost!rshost!1288!10/31/2019-22:25:49:: i INFO: Application domain type ReportManager statistics: created: 1, unloaded: 1, failed: 0, timed out: 0.
```

Can you help me please ? we encountered this issue form a week ago

Answer (score 0):

I got this on an azure VM after it was resized. I was not present, so I cant tell you what exactly happened.

Looking through the logs it gave lots of hints that it was having troubles decrypting content (connection string stuff)

The first thing I did was reimport the Key.

The second issue seemed to be that it could not find a stored procedure named GetOrAnnounceKey.

THis is strange because I looked for it on other SSRS boxes that are working fine, none of them have it.

They system in question reports version 14.0.600.1453

[I found a website that has the source for the SP enter link description here](https://ftpdocs.broadcom.com/phpdocs/0/common/impcd/r11/MDBMain/Schema15/ReportServer/Programmability/Stored_Procedures/AnnounceOrGetKey.html)

I can tell you that my server started working again. 
I can not tell you why, and I certainly cant promise you this is the right thing to do. 
It may help you get all your reports backed up if that's your goal.

If i have any problems, Ill come back and either update or delete this post.